# Proper way of creating a GUI to process selected files in a context-menu shell extension

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, com, shell-extensions

When writing context-menu shell extensions, I like the approach of just capturing the list of selected files on which the user right-clicked, and then pass them to an external program in some way. The main work is done in the external program, which has its own GUI, and runs in a separate process. The shell extension code just passes the list of selected files to the external program.

(It seems to me that this approach is followed also by other utilities, like 7-zip.)

But would it be possible to create e.g. a dialog-box directly from inside the shell extension, inside Explorer process? My understanding is that the code in the shell extension should try to do as few things as possible, and return the control to Explorer, to not hang Explorer process.

If I create a dialog-box inside the shell extension handler (e.g. in my implementation of `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`), what would be the right approach to follow?

Assuming that in dialog-box `OnInitDialog()` implementation I setup the GUI of the dialog-box, should I then call something like `DoMainWork()`, and inside this method insert a message loop to process messages?
e.g.

```
// 1. Inside context-menu shell extension implementation
//
HRESULT CMyContextMenuShellExt::InvokeCommand(...)
{
      ...
     // Build a GUI to process the selected files
     CMyDialog dlg( ...pass the list of selected files to the dialog-box ... );
     dlg.DoModal();
      ...
}

// 2. Inside CMyDialog class
//
LRESULT CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    ... prepare the GUI of the dialog-box

    DoMainWork();     
}

// 3. Inside CMyDialog::DoMainWork():
//  
for (... loop to iterate over selected files ...) {
    ... do some processing for current file

    // Process messages
    // (including e.g. the pressing of a "Stop" button by the user)
    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, m_hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find something on this? I have having a similar problem where I have to display a dialog from within Context-Menu Handler. It shows weird behavior as not being able to click on other windows till this dialog is active. Did you find the preferred approach?

Comment: @A9S6: I just passed data from the shell extension to an external .EXE, that in turn creates the dialog-box.